# Read List Stream and show on List View Firebase Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I'm struggling on this for days now:

```
      static Future<List<Job>> getJobs() async {
double lat = await MySharedPreferences.instance.getDoubleValue('lat');
print(lat);
double long = await MySharedPreferences.instance.getDoubleValue('long');
print(long);

GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: lat, longitude: long);
var collectionReference = _firestore.collection('Job_data');

Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
    .collection(collectionRef: collectionReference)
    .within(center: center, radius: 50, field: 'position');
stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
  for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.length; i++) {
    jobtype.add(snapshot[i].data()['type']);
    print(jobtype[i]);
  }
});
   }
    }

    class BodyLayout extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return _myListView(context);
}
}

Widget _myListView(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: jobtype.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(title: Text(jobtype[index]));
  });
}
```

I want to show the outcome of `Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>>` stream on my list view.

If I print `print(jobtype[i]);` I see the required values coming from firebase, but I didn't find a working solution so far for adding those values to a list view. I think I need a `Streambuilder`, but it's not working for me with `StreamList`. Unfortunately GeoFlutterFire only returns `StreamList`.

Can someone please show me a way how to show these values properly in a list view? With my current "solution" it shows the values on my list view, but they are double and not properly loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by creating a list from the stream, then using that list with the ListView.builder

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> _newList = [];

Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
    .collection(collectionRef: collectionReference)
    .within(center: center, radius: 50, field: 'position');
stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.length > 0){
       _newList = snapshot;
    }

});
.
.
.
.
ListView.builder(
     itemCount: _newList.length,
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
        return ListTile(
           title: Text(_newList[index].data["name"]);
         );
      }
)
```